# Discord.js - Message edit/delete logger error

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to add a code to my bot that logs whenever a user edits/deletes a message. The bot sends an embed to a specified channel with the information of the event. However, there's this error that I've been stuck on for a long while now, with no identified solution.

Here's the error that follows:

```
RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values may not be empty.
```

Here's the code:

```
client.on("messageUpdate", message => {
  var messages = [] 
  if(messages.includes(message.id)){return;}
  channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get('channelID')
  const channel9 = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === 'id');
  const ediembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(1752220)
    .setTitle(":pencil: Message Edited")
    .addFields (
      {name: "__Channel:__", value: `<\#${message.channel.id}>`},
      {name: "__Message Author:__", value: `${message.author.tag} - <\@${message.author.id}>`},
      {name: "__Original Message:__", value: message.content}
        
      )
    .setTimestamp()
    .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL())
    .setFooter("super cool api")
  channel9.send(ediembed)
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

2 fixes,
1: you dont need to get `channel`
2: try sending to channel a different way

```
client.on("messageUpdate", (message) => {
  var messages = [];
  if (messages.includes(message.id)) {
    return;
  }
  const ediembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(1752220)
    .setTitle(":pencil: Message Edited")
    .addFields(
      { name: "__Channel:__", value: `<\#${message.channel.id}>` },
      {
        name: "__Message Author:__",
        value: `${message.author.tag} - <\@${message.author.id}>`,
      },
      { name: "__Original Message:__", value: message.content }
    )
    .setTimestamp()
    .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL())
    .setFooter("super cool api");
  client.channels.cache.get("CHANNEL ID").send(ediembed);
});
```

Comment: Thank you!

It worked once, before killing the bot. It logged the edited message and then killed the code, displaying this error:
`if (!value) throw new RangeError('EMBED_FIELD_VALUE');
RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values may not be empty.`

Comment: Also I updated the code, try that aswell.

Comment: Yeah, I got the same error.
`/Desktop/indiansec/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:432
    if (!value) throw new RangeError('EMBED_FIELD_VALUE');
RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values may not be empty.
    at Function.normalizeField`

Below that is just the path of the file with a few other lines.